# tensorflow dataset: sort some data, then batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, pipeline

my sequential data has a wide range of lengths. Right now my dataset takes randomly shuffled sequences and pads the batch to the longest sequence. (see code below)

What I want is the following:

1.) Take randomly 20 times batch_size sequences

2.) sort them to their length (the lengths are available as "utt_lengths")

3.) batch this "sorted data" into 20 batches

my pipeline without that sorting:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.state['train_data_TFR'])
dataset = dataset.map(self.parse,num_parallel_calls=5)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000, seed=seed)
dataset = dataset.map(Pipeline.__expand)
shape = {
        "length": 1,
        "num_of_turns": 1,
        "utt_lengths": tf.TensorShape([None])
}

for turn in range(self.state['max_turns'] + 1):
    shape["utt_" + str(turn)] = tf.TensorShape([None])

dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.padded_batch_and_drop_remainder(self.state['batch_size'],
                                                                        padded_shapes=shape))

dataset = dataset.map(Pipeline.__deflate)
```

Example:

```
batch_size = 3
sort_size = 6

1.) take 6 sequences randomly from your train data:
abc
defg
fb
ghijk
a
dfg

2.) sort by sequence length:
a
fb
abc
dfg
defg
ghijk

3.) batch the data:
1. batch: a, fb, abc
2. batch: dfg, defg, ghijk
```

What i implemented is shown in my code above. That is my pipeline without this sorting. I have no clue on how I can take "n times batch size" data first, then sort and after that batch that data into "batch size" examples :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's exactly is your question? What did you try, what didn't you understand ? Take the [quick guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I added an example and some information about my actual status, thank you! :)